# Download link in django

Tags: django

Can someone help me in django when downloading a file. I have this code:

```
<a href="#">Download</a>
```

I have a pdf file in my static folder and once I click it, the pdf file will be downloaded.
Can you help me with this?

Comment: "#" isn't a link to anything.  Probably need to have something more like a path to the file.  {{ STATIC_URL }}subdir/filename.pdf

Comment: yeah, i know. hehe. i just wanna know what's the correct syntax inside the href. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/pdf/yourPDFfilename.pdf">Download</a>`

If I understand the question, this should work. `MEDIA_URL` is set in your project `settings.py` file and will aliases to the value you set in `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Comment: oh i see, so when you put {{MEDIA_URL}}/pdf/pdfname.pdf, this will automatically download the file?

Comment: thanks Al Deluca, because i tried to search in the internet, there are so many other functions that they are using. The output is always give an error. well, thank you sir. :D